# styling internally-linked div when it becomes focused

Tags: css, html, hyperlink

Is there any way to style an internally-linked div when it becomes focused? Like say I've got a link at the top of a page that I internally link (`<a href="samepage.html#more">`) to a div further down the page (`<div id="more">`), when someone clicks to that div, is there any way to style it to show that it's focused (like I'd maybe use a change in its background color or give it a border when it's clicked to)? It's not really like giving it a hover styling, it's more giving it styling on active or on focus or something like that. Is there any way to do that?

I'm not sure if there's just no way to do it, or if I'm being dense and there's an easy way, but I'm not seeing it so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should bind a JavaScript function to the `window.onhashchange` event:**

```
window.onhashchange = function () {

    var hashloc = window.location.hash;

    // hashloc is a string like '#focusDiv'
    // .. manipulate DOM

};
```

This miniature working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J3Edf/) example uses jQuery, and adds a CSS class to the focused `DIV` when a hash change event occurs.

The event is bound using plain JS because jQuery doesn't natively provide this hook, which may not at all be supported for older browsers as noted by Matt. To solve this I highly recommend [this jQuery plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) for simple hash events.

Comment: Hi, paislee. Thanks a lot. I'm not so hot on all things starting with a 'j', but I'll look into all of this. Appreciate your help.

Comment: paislee, thanks, man. That will do it. Just tested it. It rocks.

Answer (score 0):

Divs don't have a focus property that I'm aware of, but you'd probably want to bind to an event when the hash in the URL changes, then apply the changes to the div with an ID of the value of the hash.

For example, bind to this event: [window.onhashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange) -- it will only work on modern browsers (ie8+, Chrome 5+, Firefox 3.6+, etc) without some tweaking.

Comment: Hi. Okay. Thanks. Would using a table maybe work then? I'm really not sure how to bind an event to the URL though. Do you mean with javascript?

Comment: Yep - You might want to use jQuery. It's really easy with jQuery. In fact, I think it would look something like this: `$(window).bind("onhashchange", function(e) { // Change style here });`

Comment: Okay. Thanks, Matt. I'll look into that. Appreciate it.